# Sharepoint in PHP

Tags: php, sharepoint

I have on my ftp space(folder test1) the following directory/file:

- /Thybag
- test.php

I am using the API for SP: [THYBAG](https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API)

This is my code php:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/Thybag/SharePointAPI.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Thybag/Auth/SharePointOnlineAuth.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Thybag/Auth/SoapClientAuth.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Thybag/Auth/StreamWrapperHttpAuth.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Thybag/Service/ListService.php';   
require_once __DIR__ . '/Thybag/Service/QueryObjectService.php';
include "/Thybag/SharePointAPI.php";

$sp = new SharePointAPI('xx@test.it', 'pass', 'https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/HD1/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl', 'SPONLINE');
$listContents = $sp->read('<list_name>'); 
foreach($listContents as $item){
  var_dump($item); 
}
```

When I run it I get the following error:
*Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /membri/xxx/test1/Thybag/Auth/SharePointOnlineAuth.php on line 11*

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: You need to install and enable PHP's Soap-extension. That library seem to be using it to communicate with SharePoint's API.

Comment: My domain does not allow Soap to be enabled, are there any alternatives?

Comment: The library you're using seem to depend on and use PHP's SoapClient extension so if you can't install/enable that, you can't use that library. Or is it in SharePoint you're not allowed to enable their Soap service (unclear what you mean by _"my domain does not allow Soap to be enabled"_?) Either way, you won't be able to use this lib. I don't know if there are any other way. You need to do more research.